# Can I delete /swapfile after I reassigned new larger swap on other partition?

Tags: swap, delete

My swapfile at / was installed long time ago and since I need larger amount of swap now I assigned it on another partition for swap, so I would like to know that if I can delete the older one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check/verify that the old swapfile is not in use
Show a summary of swap device(s) in use

```
swapon -s
```

If the old swapfile is in use:
 - disable swap on it
 - remove -if exists- the `/etc/fstab` entry for this old swapfile

```
swapoff /old/swapfile
## and edit /etc/fstab to remove the line referring to /old/swapfile
```

Then it is safe to delete the old swapfile

```
sudo rm /old/swapfile
```

More information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq